# How is user saved in user_spec.rb test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Mike Hartl's book gives the below for [Listing 6.17](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#code-validates_uniqueness_of_email_case_insensitive_test) for a test for the rejection of duplicate email addresses, insensitive to case.

The call to `User.new` creates an in memory user but nowhere is `@user.save` called to save it to the database.

Running the test, it correctly rejects the duplicate address. But I can't figure out how it works. Only `user_with_same_email` is saved to the database not `@user`. So how could the validity test detect the duplicate without `@user` saved?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  subject { @user }
  .
  .
  .
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `@user` need not be saved to run the validity check. The rspec expression `it { should_not be_valid }` calls `@user.valid?` under the hood. This method can be run on an ActiveRecord instance whether or not it has been saved.

Answer (score 3):

`user_with_same_email` is actually saved in the database.

Notice that subject is `@user`.

`subject { @user }`

Hence, example `it { should_not be_valid }` is executed on implied subject which is `@user`.

`@user.valid?` returns false as you have put `uniqueness constraint` on the `email address` and there is already a record with same email address in your database(recall `user_with_same_email` that was saved).

So, your test example passes as `@user` is not valid.